# Unity. Move player when mobile moves (android VR)

Tags: unity-game-engine, accelerometer, virtual-reality

i'm developing VR using google cardboard SDK..
i want to move on virtual environment when i walk on real world, like this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZG5__Z9pzs&feature=youtu.be&t=48

is it possible to make VR application like that for android...? maybe using accelerometer sensor ? how can i implement this using unity...?

i try to record accelerometer sensor while i walk with smartphone, here are  the result : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ltPwS7-3nOI  [i think the accelerometer value is so random -___- ]

Answer (score 0):

[**Actually it is not possible with only mobile**:](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1169937/how-can-i-get-movement-when-a-mobile-device-moves.html)

You're up against a fundamental limitation of the humble IMU (the primary motion sensor in a smartphone).

I won't go into detail, but basically you need an external reference frame when trying to extract positional data from acceleration data. **This is the topic of a lot of research right now, and it's why VR headsets that track position like the Oculus Rift have external tracking cameras**.

Unfortunately, what you're trying to do is impossible without using the camera on your phone to track visual features in the scene and use those as the external reference point, which is a hell of a task better suited to a lab full of computer vision experts.

**[One another possible but difficult way is](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/216701/using-the-accelerometer-to-move-a-player-as-the-re.html):**

This may be possible if you connect device to internet then watch it's position from satelite(google maps or something like that)but that is a very hard thing to do.